# How to take zero or more params with Lift Web Framework

Tags: lift

How can I write a snippet that will take either zero or more params and make them available to me in the render method?

I can't seem to find a complete example anywhere, basically what I want is to be able to take

```
localhost:8080
localhost:8080/
localhost:8080/somevalue
```

and be able to access a case object that is either Full(someValue) or Empty.

Something like this basically, from https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Location_Parameters

```
menu = Menu.params[(Product,ProductReview)](
  "ProdInfo",
  "Product Information",
  ids => {
    case prodId :: revId :: Nil =>
      (findProductById(prodId), findReviewById(revId)) match {
        case (Full(product), Full(review)) => Full((product, review))
        case _ => Empty
      }
    case _ =>
      Empty
  }
  productandreview => {
    case (product, review) =>
      getIdForProduct(product) :: getIdForReview(review) :: Nil
  }
) / "products" >> If(() => S.loggedIn_?, () => RedirectResponse("/login"))
```

I want to do an even simpler version of that and would appreciate any help.  I have been working with the "shop with me" and "pocketchange" example projects, but haven't figured out how to connect all the dots yet.

Comment: You can use reactive-routing (with reactive-web-lift) from github.com/nafg/reactive

Answer (score 0):

If you want quicker responses you should probably look into the Lift's official support channel, and that is their mailing list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb

To handle the URL you have several options. Ones that I know of are:

- just get the URL and handle it manually, via `S.uri` / `s.request.*.uri`
- use REST. You can specify an unknown or optional path there. https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/REST_Web_Services

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solutions would be to have a wrapper, like:

```
case class ProductTupleMode(items:Box[(Product,ProductReview)] = Empty)
```

Then you can would setup your site rule to be something like below:

```
menu = Menu.params[ProductTupleMode](
  "ProdInfo",
  "Product Information",
  ids => {
    case prodId :: revId :: Nil =>
      (findProductById(prodId), findReviewById(revId)) match {
        case (Full(product), Full(review)) => 
          Full(ProductTupleMode(Box !! (product, review)))
        case _ => Full(ProductTupleMode())
      }
    case _ =>
      Full(ProductTupleMode())
  },
  productandreview => {
    case ProductTupleMode(Full((product, review))) =>
      getIdForProduct(product) :: getIdForReview(review) :: Nil
  }
) / "products" / ** >> If(() => S.loggedIn_?, () => RedirectResponse("/login"))
```

And in your snippet snippet you could then use either value:

```
class MySnippet(m:ProductTupleMode) {
  def render = m match {
    case Full(m.items) => ...
    case _ => ...
  }
}
```

I think that would be the cleanest and easiest to follow, but if you really need to have the signature `Box[(Product, ProductReview)]` in your snippet then you could also return `Box[Box[(Product, Product)]]` like this:

```
menu = Menu.params[Box[(Product,ProductReview)]](
  "ProdInfo",
  "Product Information",
  ids => {
    case prodId :: revId :: Nil =>
      (findProductById(prodId), findReviewById(revId)) match {
        case (Full(product), Full(review)) => Full(Full((product, review)))
        case _ => Full(Empty)
      }
    case _ =>
       Full(Empty)
  },
  productandreview => {
    case Full((product, review)) =>
      getIdForProduct(product) :: getIdForReview(review) :: Nil
  }
) / "products" / ** >> If(() => S.loggedIn_?, () => RedirectResponse("/login"))
```

Comment: Are you missing commas at the end of the ids => { } blocks?

Comment: yes, it appears they are. I had just copied and edited that block from the question where it looks like it is missing as well. I updated the answer, though I can't say that code will work without other modifications as I haven't actually tested it - just used it to illustrate a solution.